# Use Django sessions in URL

Tags: django, session, django-sessions

I currently am using Django to have users enter information via a form, and the data is then saved as a session. I then use this session to call the entered data in other views. I was wondering if it is possible to use this entered data stored in these sessions in my urls?

```
def search(request):
    result = {}

    context = RequestContext(request) 

    t = request.session.get("tick")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        search = Search(data=request.POST)


        if search.is_valid():
            ticker = search.cleaned_data['search']

            request.session["tick"] = ticker

        else:
            print search.errors
    else:
        search = Search()

    return render_to_response('ui/search.html', {"result":result}, context)
```

and here is my corresponding urls.py:

```
url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search'),
```

Is there any way I can use the session that is saved as 't = request.session.get("tick")' in my urls so I could get the urls to correspond with the data the user entered? For example if the user entered, 'hello' then my urls would show /search/hello.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it like this:

urls.py

```
url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search'),
url(r'^search/(?P<query>.+)/$', views.search, name='search'),
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def search(request, query=None):
    result = {}
    context = RequestContext(request) 

    if request.method == 'POST':
        search = Search(data=request.POST)
        if search.is_valid():
            ticker = search.cleaned_data['search']
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('search', kwargs={'query': ticker}))
        else:
            print search.errors
    else:
        search = Search()

    return render_to_response('ui/search.html', {"result":result}, context)
```